# Stuck throttle open on specialized turbo electric pedal-assist bike

Tags: electric-bike

The throttle is stuck open on my 2016 specialized turbo.  How do I adjust or fix?  Note there is no throttle switch, and is a torque pedal assist mechanism. (it senses how hard you are pedaling to turn on the motor). Is there a screw I can turn to adjust the sensor?  Where is the sensor located, is it in the axle/motor?  Will adjusting the tension on the derailer help?

Comment: Clarification of the problem is needed here. There is no 'throttle' control on pedal assist e-bikes, just a setting for the amount of assistance, so there is nothing to 'get stuck'. Are you saying the motor delivers max torque regardless of pedaling force or speed?

Comment: This sounds like either a sensor failure or its mis-configured to be a motorbike.  Sounds like an issue to take up directly with specialised.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus yes, the motor is on and at high output even when I'm not pedaling or putting any pressure/torque on the pedals.  In fact it just starts spinning as soon as I turn it on.

Answer (score 4):

There is no 'throttle' control on pedal assist e-bikes, just a setting for the amount of assistance, so there is nothing to 'get stuck'.

If the motor spins the wheel aand delivers max torque regardless of pedaling force or speed, there is an electronic control problem. Most likely a sensor is broken, or even just come loose.

The only thing you can do is take it to a Specialized dealer bike store. Only they will have the knowledge and tools to diagnose the issue and fix it.